# UICollectionView cell content do not resize

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I´m doing a photogallery with a UICollectionView, and when the device rotates I update the cell size to fill the UICollectionView. The cell turns into the correct size but the problem is that the image  stays with the previous size.

**Here's how it looks like:** 
https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8845/17954876314_0359804127_b.jpg

**And here's my code**

```
func setupCollectionViewLayout() {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    var itemWidth=view.bounds.size.width;

    if(itemWidth==414)
    {
        itemWidth = (view.bounds.size.width - 2) / 3
    }
    else
    {
        if(itemWidth == 1024)
        {
            itemWidth = (view.bounds.size.width - 10) / 5
        }
        else
        {
            if(itemWidth == 768)
            {
                itemWidth = (view.bounds.size.width - 4) / 5
            }
            else
            {
                itemWidth = (view.bounds.size.width + 5) / 3
            }

        }
    }
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
    layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionView!.bounds.size.width, height: 50.0)
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

Comment: You are resizing the cells but not the images, apply the layout itemSize to the image too.

Comment: I think you need to set to the image and try to use view.frame.size.width instead of view.bounds.size.width, because it's getting the size of the container or the superview of the image.